# Access button from external class

Tags: android

In my app I have an Activity `LoginUserActivity` that contains a button perform a connection to a web-server using JSONObject request and Volley. If the login is successfull will be launched another activity, but if it isn't I need to re-enable the button.

**LoginUserActivity**

```
public void OnLoginUtente(View view) {
    final String mail = etMail.getText().toString();
    final String pw = etPassword.getText().toString();

    bLogin.setEnabled(false);

    DBConnection connection = new DBConnection(mail, pw, getApplicationContext());
    connection.doLogin();
}
```

**doLogin()**

```
public void doLogin() {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("type", type);
        obj.put("email", email);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, obj,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(context, response.getString("Status"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (response.getString("Esito").equals("true")) {
                            intent = new Intent(context, MainUtente.class);
                            context.startActivity(intent); 
                        }else{
                            //I think I've to put something here
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }
    );

    jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.getCache().clear();
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

I've tried different things, such as make `doLogin()` return a boolean and then re-enable the button from the activity or try to inflate the layout of the calling activity in the `else`, but neither of these worked. If possible I'd like to keep the `doLogin()` method void and without parameters.

Comment: why don't you disable the button in json onResponse before launching the activity?

Comment: Because I don't know how to access to the button. That's my problem.

Comment: Because `doLogin()` is defined in a class that performs also the registration and other stuff. Moreover I call the `doLogin()` method in other activities as whell.

Comment: well to me, `LoginActivity` should handle all the logging in. But if you want to do it like this, like I said, you can reference `LoginActivity` and call a method that disables the button right before launching your new activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoginUserActivity

```
public void OnLoginUtente(View view) {
    final String mail = etMail.getText().toString();
    final String pw = etPassword.getText().toString();

    DBConnection connection = new DBConnection(mail, pw, getApplicationContext());
    connection.doLogin(this);
}

public void disableLoginButton()
{
    bLogin.setEnabled(false);
}
```

doLogin

```
public void doLogin(final LoginActivity activity) {
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
try {
    obj.put("type", type);
    obj.put("email", email);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, obj,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(context, response.getString("Status"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (response.getString("Esito").equals("true")) {
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable(){
                            public void run() {
                                activity.disableLoginButton();
                            }
                        );

                        activity.disableLoginButton();
                        intent = new Intent(context, MainUtente.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent); 
                    }else{
                        //I think I've to put something here
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
}
);

jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
requestQueue.getCache().clear();
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

You may replace `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(runnable)` with `activity.runOnUiThread(runnable)`

Comment: I didn't use your exact same code, but I kept tour idea. Thanks